# ubuntu 16.04 samba not connecting to windows 7

Tags: networking, windows-7, samba

Windows 7 Pro and Ubuntu 16.04
Windows machine originally set to Homegroup - turned that off.
Windows can "see" the Ubuntu machine, pings it, comes up in the list, will not access any information.

Ubuntu Network "sees" windows computers and Windows network icon on first page. Unable to access location error. Windows network has folder WORKGROUP, which lists ubuntu machine and windows 7 machine. 
Ubuntu icon only brings up print$, and Windows icon clicking gives same error message. Unable to access location. Failed to retrieve share list from server: No route to host.

[ edit ] want to share all files and folders.|
samba installed.

edit on samba config file.
name resolve order = bcast host
SOLVED

Comment: You need to configure the network shares before anything else and it seems haven't done anything of the sort. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: I did this once before with Utuntu 14 and Windows XP.
Where do I configure the network shares, and how?
I assume it should be done in Ubuntu - I have been through all the networking menus ( that I can find ) on the windows machine.

Comment: Windows instructions are off-topic here. That said it shouldn't be so different than in XP. The rest depends on what you really want to do and your question as it is now smells like "totally clueless". Please edit and describe what is the intended result, i.e., what network resources are supposed to be shared and from what, and what have you done so far.